# How do we discriminate binomials with ordinary pairs of words?

Tags: phrases

There's an interesting topic that I've seen on my book i.e. ***Binomials** [expressions (often idiomatic) where two words are joined by a conjunction (usually 'and')*]. The book gives a lot of examples and it seems that each binomial has its unique meaning.

For instance, these are sentences that I've taken from my book:

> 1. **Pick and choose** [have a wide choice]
> 2. **Peace and quiet** [a peaceful/calm situation]
> 3. **Take it or leave it**
> 4. **Back to front** [the wrong way]

Now, related to my question in the title, what's the difference or how do we know whether the pairs are binomials or just ordinary pairs of words or pair of near synonyms?

If there's no difference, Can I make my own binomials using words as long as they sound natural?

I mean, the pairs in bold below that I've randomly chose, are they binomials as well?

1. My boyfriend is **handsome and tall**.
2. **Black or white** is not important before the law.
3. I heard someone on my room last night. She was **shouting and screaming**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Thoughtco *binomials in English*](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-binomial-words-1689027)

> In language studies, a pair of words (for example, loud and clear) **conventionally** linked by a conjunction (usually and) or a preposition is called a binomial, or a binomial pair.

[emphasis added]

The word *conventionally* suggests that while you can put words together any way you want, a pairing would become a binomial only if it was widely accepted.

"Tall and handsome" is common, but in that order. "Shouting and screaming" is common.

The link discusses various types of binomials - irreversible and reversible, synomymous, and echoic, for example. It mentions trinomials too.